# Error en mi registro mod_fcgid: stderr PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, apache, apache2

Tengo error en mi registro de logs, cuando intento subir las imágenes mediante el Back-end, no me carga las imágenes y no sube a las carpetas que están direccionado en el script de php 7.1 y me tira este error "mod_fcgid: stderr thrown in /home/user1/public_html/backend/vista/moll/photo.php on line 70," en los logs de registros de apache2.

La linea 70 de mi codigo es :

```
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $resourceType = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileName); // linea 70
            $imageLayer = resizeImage($resourceType,$sourceImageWidth,$sourceImageHeight,$new_width,$new_height);
            imagejpeg($imageLayer,$uploadPath."photo".$resizeFileName.'.'. $fileExt);
            break;
```

---> El código en si esta bien ya lo he testeado en otros servidores corre normal se carga.

---> posiblemente sea que falta configurar bien el php 7.1 he intentado configurar bien php7.1 y nada que no me soluciona el problema y también he intentado configurar APACHE y tampoco logro dar una solución.

"NO SOY EXPERTO EN CONFIGURACIONES AUN SOY BEBE"

Por favor échame una mano.

Comment: Intenta usar una versión anterior de php, 7.0.10 por ejemplo

Comment: He intentado cambiar de version a php 7.0.10 y nada sigue sin cargar.